# Is there an elegant way to make/generate spaces instead of &nbsp?

Tags: html, css, space

I need to generate spaces in a HTML file.

Comment: For layout, so the text won't look crowded.

Comment: It is used between text/words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on the context, you can use letter-spacing, word-spacing or for example padding for surrounding span's.

Without more information it´s impossible to give a good advice.

**Edit:** if it´s for use in texts / in between words, I´d go for the word-spacing and perhaps letter-spacing.

Comment: just to add a tidbit, 1em is equal to 1 font heigth so 2em is the same space as 2 font of the current setting (context) which scales size with the text then.

Answer (score 13):

Use either `&nbsp` or `<pre>` tags. The `<pre>` tag preserves all spaces, tabs and newlines.

**EDIT**
Regarding your comment about its use, for padding, you may want to look at [css padding](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/padding.php)

Answer (score 1):

I hardly ever use `&nbsp;`

`margin` and `padding` properties work well for spacing and `<br />` for newlines. (I don't use `<br />` too frequently either.)

Answer (score 0):

&nbsp; is a non-breaking space. Alternatively I guess you could use a `<br />` (XHTML there) tag just to generate a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Yacoby is right. But i have something different:

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    .left-space { margin-left: 10px; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div>
   <p>This is a test line.<span class="left-space">This is a line with space before it.</span></p>
</div>

</body>
```

And by the way you should replace `&nbsp;` with `&#160;` to conform to XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

i use a span with css classes.
i have several class like spacer_1, spacer_2, spacer_3, etc..
i use different horizontal padding like this

```
.spacer_1
{
    padding:0px 5px;
}
```

to use this spacer you can use the following

```
<span class="spacer_1" /> /*this will generate half the gap*/
<span class="spacer_1"></span>
<span class="spacer_1">|</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```css
/* in your css code:  */ 
pre
{
  display:inline;   
}
```

```html
<!-- and then, in your HTML markup: -->

<pre>    this text comes after 4 spaces.</pre>
<span> continue the line with other element without braking </span>
```